# How do I click a button in a DialogBox automatically in Excel using Visual C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop, excel-interop

I made a program that makes ChartSheets automatically from a set of data in a datasheet; I want to delete all of the ChartSheets that I made; I made some code to delete all of the ChartSheets, but it requires me to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm a DialogBox to delete the ChartSheet, this is for each ChartSheet. It is cumbersome, so I want to automate that.

This is my code so far:

```
while(currentApplication.Charts.Count > 0)
{
   currentApplication.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMaximized;
   SetForegroundWindow(currentApplication.Hwnd);
   currentWorkbook.Charts.Item[1].Delete();
   SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
   SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
}
```

Comment: What is the dialog saying? Might be worth seeing if there's a reason the dialog is appearing so it could potentially be avoided. Also, check to see if currentApplication has a boolean property called DisplayAlerts. If it does, you can set it to false before you delete and then set it back to true. It seems to be present in vba according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923694/delete-sheets-and-avoid-excel-asking-the-user-to-confirm-using-custom-messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to NickProud for his suggestion, I only have to set `DisplayAlerts` to `false`, so it doesn't show the DialogBox and it automatically accepts to delete the ChartSheet (or datasheet) automatically.

Here is the updated code:

```
while(currentApplication.Charts.Count > 0)
{
   currentApplication.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMaximized;
   SetForegroundWindow(currentApplication.Hwnd);
   currentApplication.DisplayAlerts = false;
   currentWorkbook.Charts.Item[1].Delete();
   currentApplication.DisplayAlerts = true;   
}
```